# @Value can not generate value properly, getting null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I run the code the external configuration in the application.properties file does not get populated into the variable within the DataBucketUtil. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid,but I can not find out wheres the problem.

```
public class DataBucketUtil {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataBucketUtil.class);

@Value("${gcp.config.file}")
private String gcpConfigFile;

@Value("${gcp.project.id}")
private String gcpProjectId;

@Value("${gcp.bucket.id}")
private String gcpBucketId;

@Value("${gcp.directory.name}")
private String gcpDirectoryName;

/**
 * Upload file to GCS
 *
 * @param multipartFile-
 * @param fileName-
 * @param contentType-
 * @return -
 */


public FileDto uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, String fileName, String contentType) {
    try {
        logger.debug("Start file uploading process on GCS");
        byte[] fileData = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(convertFile(multipartFile));
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource(gcpConfigFile).getInputStream();

        StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(gcpProjectId)
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream)).build();

        Storage storage = options.getService();
        Bucket bucket = storage.get(gcpBucketId, Storage.BucketGetOption.fields());

        RandomString id = new RandomString(6, ThreadLocalRandom.current());
        Blob blob = bucket.create(gcpDirectoryName + "/"
                        + fileName + "-" + id.nextString() + checkFileExtension(fileName),
                fileData, contentType);

        if (blob != null) {
            logger.debug("File successfully uploaded to GCS");
            return new FileDto(blob.getName(), blob.getMediaLink());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("An error occurred while uploading data. Exception: ", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("An error occurred while uploading data to GCS");
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("An error occurred while uploading data to GCS");
}
```

My application properties is given below:

```
 gcp.config.file=gcp-config/gcs-prod-ho-finance.json
 gcp.project.id=brac-main gcp.bucket.id=prod-ho-finance
 gcp.dir.name=gs://prod-ho-finance
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear from your code snippet but my guess would be that your `DataBucketUtil` is not instantiated as a Bean and therefore the `@Value` annotated fields are not populated. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) for more details about the `@Value` annotation.

You could transform your class to a service or component with the `@Component` or `@Service` annotation and then autowire it to where you need it. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean) for more information about beans.

Answer (score 0):

Please add Annotations. I hope it work.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Component
public class DataBucketUtil {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataBucketUtil.class);

@Value("${gcp.config.file}")
private String gcpConfigFile;

@Value("${gcp.project.id}")
private String gcpProjectId;

@Value("${gcp.bucket.id}")
private String gcpBucketId;

@Value("${gcp.directory.name}")
private String gcpDirectoryName;

/** ............ **/

}
```